# Connecting a MIDI piano keyboard to the iPad with a MIDI cable

Tags: ipad, midi, instruments

I have an iPad Pro and wanted to connect a keyboard with my iPad via a MIDI cable that I also have (https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B00NH13DV2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

And I don't know which adapter to buy to be able to do it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cable you have is actually not a MIDI cable - it is however the correct cable for many keyboards/stage pianos today. The standard MIDI plug looks quite different (it is round), but in the end you'll be able to transfer the same data over the USB cable you have.

The adapter you need depends on which version of the iPad Pro you have. For the older ones with a Lightning port, you can use for example the [Apple Lightning to USB Camera Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter). For newer iPad Pros with a USB-C port, you can use for example the [Apple USB-C to USB Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter).

Comment: I have the model A1876. Which one would suit me?

Comment: That’s the 12.9” iPad Pro (2018). You’ll need the USB-C adapter.

Comment: I would recommend some kind of dock or multi-port adapter so that you can provide power to the iPad while the MIDI keyboard is connected.  Some MIDI keyboards rely on USB for power and so may drain the iPad battery quickly.  Most any dock or multi-port adapter will do as long as it has a USB-C port for power and a USB-A port for the MIDI keyboard.  I suspect a dock that also has Ethernet and audio in/out ports would be helpful for you in the long run.